# continue clock time after page gets refreshed in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I am using javascript to Put the **timer** on my Webpage.
When start button is pressed, clock starts with timestamp.

All the thing are working properly without any error.

code is

```
initialize_timer: function() {
    this.project_m2o = new project_timesheet.FieldMany2One(this, {model: this.project_timesheet_model , classname: "pt_input_project pt_required", label: "Select a project", id_for_input: "project_id"});
    this.project_m2o.on("change:value", this, function() {
        var project = [this.project_m2o.get('value'), this.project_m2o.$input.val()];
        this.project_timesheet_db.set_current_timer_activity({project_id: project});
        this.set_project_model();
```

Now whenever page gest refreshed the clock should be continue, but it is initializing again with `00:00`.

guide me to deal with it!

Comment: You need to pass an initial time from the backend to start your timer.

Comment: Thats the behaviour of page.. you need to store timer some where which persists your time and reset when page reloads. on client application you can store timer value either in cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Store the system time when you start your timer in a cookie or in local storage.  Each time your web page loads, you can read the previous system start time and initialize the clock appropriately.

If the time needs to be less prone to tampering, then you would need to store the time on your server for each user and put the start time for that user in the page each time it is served from the server.

Comment: i stored the value of initialization of timer  with 'localstorage'. It is showing well too on console. After refreshing the page the Localstorage value remains same, nut problem I am facing is timer is set at 00:00 . how to bind timer value with localstorage

Comment: And if i am again pressing on start button then localstorage value is being updated!

Comment: @HardikAnavadia - The value in local storage should be the start time from something like `Date.now()`.  The elapsed time since the start time can be computed at any time with `Date.now() - localStorageStartTime`.  That will be the number of milliseconds since you last started the timer.